# Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 1$ is false

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 1$$

Given $\epsilon > 0$
$$\left|\frac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon.$$
Rewrite it as
$$-\epsilon < \frac{1}{x} - 1 < \epsilon$$
$$-\epsilon + 1< \frac{1}{x} < \epsilon + 1$$
If epsilon is very small, then on both sides we are getting value close to $1$, but the function gets closer to zero, hence both sides false.
If $\epsilon$ is big, then on the right side we are getting big positive value, but with $ n \in (0,1)$ the function gets bigger too. Hence right side fails.
Is this  a sound proof? And if yes, how would I rewrite it with math symbols?

Comment: I think more symbols is not the answer. Your idea is right, it just has to be phrased in the right way. Math is as much a language you have to learn, especially in how you can be precise in your speech, not being more symbolic and obscure. So for example, what you would like to do is a proof by contradiction. With a phrase, assert what you are assuming to be true (to be proven false later) and assert where the contradiction arises and why. Right now the assertions don't happen and your explanation why relies on describing a story rather than an implication (as my PDE professor put it)

Comment: This is not a proof: a proof will not rely on a verbal argument. You must find some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for any $N$, there exists $x>N$ such that $|1/x-1|\ge\varepsilon$.

Comment: @ElliotG proofs can and often are verbal, they just need to be precise, not a story explaining a mental picture.

Comment: (I agree to an extent and was just typing this) I mean technically all arguments are verbal, but a proof will not use heuristics like "closer to zero" or "big" / "small"

Comment: @ElliotG my textbook do uses them sometimes :D. But it's a school textbook, maybe that's why. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @NihadMunshi I asked about symbols mostly because I wanted to know how would you write those "musings" in a strict way. Well, turned out my musing wasn't strict in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the audience, intent, or level "closer to zero" or "big/small" may be acceptable in a proof but when it's not okay to assume impressions without reasons.  If we know $\frac 1x$ gets close to zero, that's the same thing as saying $\lim_{x\to \infty}1x=0$.  If we are asked to prove something our proof can never be "well, we know it's true".  And so a proof that $\lim_{x\to\infty}1x$ is not one cant be "well, we know it's not $1$ because it gets close to $0$; not $1$.

Comment: Although I do have to admit the question of "prove $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1x=1$ is false" seems very weird.  I would have expected being asked to "prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} 1x = 0$" instead.  So I'm not sure if the book is specically asking us to prove $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1x = 1$ leads directly to a contradiction nor whether we are allow to assume limits are always unique and $\frac 1x$ can not have two different limits.

Comment: @fleablood the book did asked for 0. It was me who plugged in 1, because I wanted to see what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would accept it, because I know what you mean by very small. However, in this case it's best to make precise what you mean. If we use 1/2, and let $x>2$, then $1/x<1/2$. So we can't have$1/x\to1$.

Honestly, the right hand side doesn't matter in this case. We only need to break one of the inequalities to show convergence doesn't hold. But in any case it is always true for $x\geq1$ that $1/x<1+\epsilon$, so the right inequality does hold.

Answer (score 5):

Your argument that $\frac 1x$ goes to $0$ needs to be proven and that basically *is* what is being asked to be proven; prove $\frac 1x$ *doesn't* go to $1$.

ANd if you *do* prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac 1x = 0$ (which it does-- see addenda) that's not enough because although the limit notation $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = L$ *looks* like an equality, it actually means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that $x > N \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ and we don't know that there *can't* be two so $L$s.  (ALthough we can and do prove that very early on-- see addenda).

Here's a hint:  $|\frac 1x - 1| =|1-\frac 1x|= |\frac {x-1}x|$.

so if $|\frac 1x - 1|<\epsilon$ then $-\epsilon < \frac {x-1}x < \epsilon$.  Now as $x\to \infty$ we can assume $x > 1$ so $-\epsilon x < 0 < x-1 < x\epsilon$

$x-x\epsilon=x(1-\epsilon) < 1$

If we choose an $\epsilon$ so that $0<\epsilon < 1$  we have $x < \frac 1{1-\epsilon}$.

Well, that puts an upper limit on $x$ which contradicts that $x \to \infty$ so that's impossible.

======

Addenda:

Claim:  $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac 1x = 0$.

Pf:  For any $\epsilon >0$ Let $N =\frac 1{\epsilon}$ (which is positive).  If $x > N$ then $|\frac 1x -0| = \frac 1x < \frac 1N =\epsilon$.

Claim:  If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L$ and $M \ne L$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= M$ is not true.

Proof:  If $L \ne M$ then $|L - M| > 0$.  Let $\epsilon = \frac {|L-M|}2$

If $|f(x) - M| < \epsilon$ and $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ then

$|L - M| = |(L - f(x)) + (f(x) - M)| \le |L-f(x)| + |f(x)-M| < \epsilon + \epsilon = |L-M|$

So $|L-M| < |L-M|$ which is impossible.  So there are no $N$ or $N'$ so that if $x >N$ and $x > N'$ (i.e. $x > \max(N,N')$ then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and $|f(x) -M| < \epsilon$ as that is impossible.

......

So if you didn't want to prove it as I did in the body of this post, you can insteand prove limits, when they exist, are unique.  And that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x =0$ and that $0 \ne 1$ so the claim $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x = 1$ is false.

Comment: $|L - M| = |(L - f(x)) + (f(x) - M)|$ I don't understand that. It says that difference between  distances between f(x) and both of the two limits (if they exist) will be the same as the distance between two limits?

Comment: No.  It's the triangle inequality.   $|A+ B| \le |A| + |B|$ and so as we *ALWAYS* have $A- B = (A- Z) + (Z-B)$ we *always* have $|A-B| = |(A-Z) + (Z-B)|\le |A-Z| + |Z-B|$.  ..... It says the distance between the two limits will be equal *OR LESS* than the sum of the  distance between the limits and any third point.  That is true for *ANY* three points.  The distance between $M$ and $N$ is *always* equal or less than the distance between $M$ and $W$ + the distance between $W$ and $N$.   ***ALWAYS***

Comment: $|(L - \text{my aunt harriet}) + (\text{my aunt harriet} - M)| = |L + (-\text{my aunt harriet} + \text{my aunt harriet}) - M| = |L + 0 - M| = |L -M|$.  And so  $|L - M| = |(L - \text{my aunt harriet}) + (\text{my aunt harriet} - M)| \le |L - \text{my aunt harriet}| + |\text{my aunt harriet} - M|= |L - \text{my aunt harriet}| + |M-\text{my aunt harriet}|$.

Comment: Thanks! Algebraic explanation is perfect! I always found those joke comparisons confusing :D

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ assume wlog $x>1$ and $\epsilon<1$ then

$$\left|\frac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon \iff1-\frac1x < \epsilon \iff \frac1x>1-\epsilon \iff x<\frac1{1-\epsilon }$$

then the inequality fails for any $x\ge M=\frac1{1-\epsilon }$.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a alternative proof method, consider the improper integral $$I=\lim_{x\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}\,dt$$

We know that since $t^2\geq 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and in this case, $t\geq 1>0$, so we have that $1\geq \frac{1}{t^2}>0$, which implies that the function in the integrand is strictly positive on the interval $[1,\infty)$, so the integral should be strictly positive as well, that is, $I>0$. After computing, we see that $$I=\lim_{x\to\infty} -\frac{1}{t}\bigg|_{t=1}^{t=x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{1}{x}+1=\lim_{x\to\infty}-(\frac{1}{x}-1)=-(1-1)=0\not>0$$

So, the assumption that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}=1$ is false.

Comment: ***WHOA*** NO REASON TO DELETE THE POST!  ... The post in general is valid..." Then we have that for all ε>0,
∣∣∣1x−1∣∣∣<ε"  You know.... I can't let that stand. We *don't* have that.  Consider the *true* statement $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac 1x = 0$.  Then we would claim.  "For all $\epsilon>0$, $|\frac 1x-0|<\epsilon$". That's obviously not true.  If $\epsilon=\frac 1{10}$ then $|\frac 1x - 0|<\epsilon$ is only true if $x > 10$. It's not true if $0<x<10$. and in general it won't be true for any $0<x < \frac 1 \epsilon$ which always exist.  We need to be a *little* more careful in what we state.

Comment: @fleablood sorry, thanks for pointing this out. To clean it up, should I state that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $x$ such that the property holds? What would you recommend  to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To show that the statement is false, find an $\epsilon$ which does not have a corresponding $x^\star$, such that whenever $x \geq x\star$, $| \frac{1}{x} - 1 | < \epsilon$ does not hold. Suppose $L = 1$ and let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.
Consider when $x^\star \geq 1$, then
\begin{align*}
| \frac{1}{x} -1 | \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

whenever $x \geq 2$. Consider when $x^\star <1$, then
\begin{align*}
|\frac{1}{x} -1 | \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
whenever $x \geq 2$.

Hence, there does not exist an $x^\star$ for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, it must certainly be false that the limit is $1$.